# помощь в PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

Добрый день! Решил попробовать отправить тестовое письмо на e-mail при помощи PHPMailer. Залил все это на хотинг hosting.timeweb.ru. Возвращает код ошибки 500. Скрипт вот такой:

```
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail -> isSMTP();
$mail -> Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> Username = 'test.test@mail.ru';
$mail -> Password = 'testtest';
$mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail -> Port = 465;
$mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail -> setFrom('test.test@mail.ru','Александр');

$mail -> addAddress('AlexKul1985sanshoy@mail.ru','Александр');
$mail -> isHTML(true);
$mail -> Subject = 'Проверка связи!';
$mail -> Body = 'Привет, мир!<p>Это <b>HTML !!!</b></p>';
$mail -> AltBody = 'Привет мир!Это альтернативное письмо!';
$mail -> send();
echo $mail -> ErrorInfo;
```

Не подскажите как решить проблему? Может в .htaccess что-нибудь прописать надо?

Comment: Экстрасенсы в отпуске. Что лог апача пишет?

Comment: Спасибо! За то, что откликнулись. Там просто не был подключен отдельно файл c классом SMTP . Лог как раз таки на него ругался.)

Comment: Сейчас все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Вы пробросили SMTP сервер? Зачем это вам? Есть прекрасный Yandex PDD. Там и готовый SMTP и все, все, все из под коробки

Comment: Про YANDEX PDD не слышал! А пробросил я потому, что SMTP сервера которые предоставляются хостерами , очень часто могут находится в блок листах у серверов получателей и просто игнорироваться.По этому рекомендуют использовать сторонние SMTP сервера типа smtp.mail.ru или smtp.gmail.com. Это я где-то слышал .. но, все равно спасибо за совет!